Korean action movie with 1 woman preparing 3 girls
I don't remember whether that's a korean movie or Japanese movie, but it was an action film.
There were 3 girls with some powers. They were being trained by a woman. But the woman in order to get rid of their only possible weakness, gets the 3 girls being raped by strangers on dining table itself (After drugging the girls).
The girls later on takes revenge on the woman, thereby killing her at the end. Don't remember anything apart from that, but it's an old movie.

Sounds like Naked Weapon (2002). It is a Chinese action movie with martial arts.
Plot:

The movie opens with the assassination of a man of unknown identity. A team of three CIA officers, including Jack Chen (played by Daniel Wu), a rookie, watch through surveillance as a sexy female assassin named Fiona Birch (Marit Thoresen) enters the man's heavily guarded apartment suite and, after having sex with him, kills him by breaking his spine with her bare hands. As she makes her escape in her white Porsche 911 GT3, her car is hit by a rocket. As the officers rush over to extricate her from the wreckage, a woman in a limousine shoots her to death.

And the particular scene you were talking about takes place on a dining table.

After six years of gruesome training, only Charlene Ching (Maggie Q), Katt (Anya Wu) and Jing (Jewel Lee) survive and "graduate". The last test in order for them to graduate was a fight for survival/to the death test. Katt and Charlene, being friends, could not kill each other, and so each is accepted as the third survivor. To celebrate, Madame M gives them all different wines which have drugs in it. As the drugs take effect Madame M calls her guards to brutally rape the girls, thus (in Madame M's words) making them ready for what was to come.

